# Union query with different numbers of columns

Tags: mysql, select, union

It is for sure a simple question but I can't fix an MySQL query: 
I want to run below prepared query

```
select id from table1 where c_id = :c_id 
union 
select id,name from table2 where c_id = :c_id and temp = :temp
```

So I have different numbers of column in each table select's output. Is this the reason it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `SELECT` a literal value in the first query, like so:

```
SELECT id, 'no name' AS "name" FROM table1 WHERE c_id = :c_id
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name                FROM table2 WHERE c_id = :c_id 
                                             AND temp = :temp;
```

Comment: @user1611830 - No, you should put it in the sql query string directly without parameters, becuase it is a literal value like a constant string value. Put it with qutes.

Comment: IN fact, my post was to simplify this query that is not working : select id, 'noname' as "confirm" from table1 where c_id = :c_id union select id, 'noname' as "confirm" from table2 where c_id = :c_id union select id, confirm from table3 where c_id = :c_id and confirm =1

Comment: to be more precise i f I isolate this query 'select id from table2 where c_id = :c_id' works, but this doesn't 'select id, 'noname' as "confirm" from table2 where c_id = :c_id'

Comment: @user1611830 I am not good IN PHP. But try to put a space in the end of each line, if you write the query in multi line, also print the query before executing it, to see what the problem.

Comment: ok fixed by passing double quotes to wrap 'noname' (becoming "noname")